# ¿ Como incluir un archivo aspx dentro de un archivo html?

Tags: asp.net

En una wep con ASP necesito que aparezca la URL de inicio de una pagina con la extensión .HTML
¿ Cómo puedo hacer para incluir un trozo de código en aspx dentro de un archivo HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que incluir la etiqueta de iframe en tu codigo html, y poner la direccion que quieras.

```
<div class="embed-container">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="URL" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.embed-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Extraido y probado --> https://cybmeta.com/como-hacer-un-iframe-responsive

Comment: El problema con esta solución es que el contenido del iframe no es reponsivo, no se adaptaría a los distintos tamaños de la ventana del navegador.

Comment: ahi te puse un codigo que acabo de probar.

Comment: Probando ese código es una solución a medias.  Tampoco me acaba de funcionar bien ya que me sale una barra lateral en la ventana del iframe porque el contenido no se expande a todo su height o alto. Solo debería salir la barra lateral en la ventana padre que contiene el iframe.